# VSCode extension command arguments

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to register command which is going to call vscode built-in command with specified argument.

However, argument seems to be ignored.

What am I doing wrong, where can I find types of arguments that are supposed to be given for a specific command?

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('my.command', () => {
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.removeRootFolder', vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders![0].uri);
});
```